# What Japanese term would be used to describe the image that Japanese see when they look at the moon?

Tags: meaning, words, culture

What do Japanese see when they look at the moon? In America, we see the face of a man. Is it the same in Japan? A fellow Japanese learner asked me this question online.

Comment: Is this a question about the Japanese language in any way?

Comment: I see your edit to the title. I'm not sure just asking for the answer to be in Japanese makes the question about the language.

Comment: `What term is used ...  "mochi pounding rabbits"` -- So this is not about the Japanese language, is it?

Comment: @chocolate, I used the culture tag. The Japanese term would be helpful.

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%88%E3%81%AE%E5%85%8E

Comment: Presumably the culture tag is for questions about how the language is used in Japanese culture (like politeness levels).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is asking for help with pop-culture names, and does not relate to the cultural usage of the Japanese language.

Comment: I don't want to close the question, because the answer received benefits users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually seen as "mochi-pounding rabbits" -> 月の兎 (https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%88%E3%81%AE%E5%85%8E)

Comment: Now I am able to research the term. it was adopted from other Asian cultures.